Parameter Passing Using Javascript's Fetch
I'm working on a legacy system looking at ways to increase performance. It's an MVC project with C# backend (upgraded to .net 8) and a Javascript/JQuery front-end. The front-end code is using AJAX to make it's calls and it's all working fine but I'm trying to switch it to using Fetch, and I've hit a bit of a brickwall. The server side routines all use the following style:
public IActionResult SearchCerts(string Company, string ExpStart, string ExpEnd)
{
...
  return PartialView("_SearchResults", Results);
}

and they're called using:
function SearchCerts() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Certs/SearchCerts",
        data: { 
            Company: document.getElementById("edtSearchCompany").value,
            ExpStart: document.getElementById("edtSearchExpires1").value,
            ExpEnd: document.getElementById("edtSearchExpires2").value
        },
        dataType: "html",
        async: true,
        success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $('#divSearchResults').html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Error");
        }
    });
}

When I try to use Fetch, all of the parameters come across as null and the only way I seem to be able to pass anything in is to update the server side routine to accept an IFormCollection parameter (pulling out the individual values when needed) and pass in a FormData variable like so:
async function SearchCertsExecute() {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Company', document.getElementById("edtSearchCompany").value);
    formData.append('ExpStart', document.getElementById("edtSearchExpires1").value);
    formData.append('ExpEnd', document.getElementById("edtSearchExpires2").value);

    let Results = await fetch("/Certs/SearchCerts", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    });

    if (Results.ok) {
        var data = await Results.text();

        $('#divSearchResults').html(data);
    } else {
        alert("HTTP-Error: " + Results.status);
    }
}

I've tried creating a Javascript object containing the and then using JSON.stringify but still the server gets nothing but nulls:
    var SendData = {
    Company: document.getElementById("edtSearchCompany").value,
    ExpStart: document.getElementById("edtSearchExpires1").value,
    ExpEnd: document.getElementById("edtSearchExpires2").value
    };

    let Results = await fetch("/Certs/SearchCerts", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(SendData)
    });

Can anybody shed any light on what I'm missing?

Your jQuery version seems to make a GET request (which is the default if you don't have a type or method property) while your fetch version makes a POST request. For GET requests, $.ajax() appends the body to the URL (as query string parameters). (I'm not an expert on .NET so I don't know if it makes a difference.)

Additionally, you can try to use some request monitoring tool like Surfshark or Fiddler Telerik to analyze what's different between the two http calls.

@Ivar Just tried switching the Fetch to specify GET and Javascript bombs out with:
Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

@TheNeil That's right. GET requests can't have a body in JavaScript. jQuery automagically changes the body to URL parameters, but fetch doesn't do this for you, so you need to do this manually.

@Ivar Having looked at what was actually being sent using the two different methods (as suggested) I did see that AJAX added the data as URL parameters and had this terrible feeling that I was going to have to do that manually with Fetch. I had no idea that JQuery was 'helping' - thanks for the insight =:)

@FernandoDelCantão or just open the browser dev tools and look at the network tab. 1. faster 2. built-in.

@TheNeil "had this terrible feeling that I was going to have to do that manually with Fetch." you don't have to. You can just leverage URL + URLSearchParams that do all the work for constructing a valid URL for you: Setting query string using Fetch GET request

I will post it as an answer because of the code
try do the fetch like this:
fetch("/Certs/SearchCerts", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        Company: document.getElementById("edtSearchCompany").value,
        ExpStart: document.getElementById("edtSearchExpires1").value,
        ExpEnd: document.getElementById("edtSearchExpires2").value
    })
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(data => {
    document.getElementById('divSearchResults').innerHTML = data;
})
.catch(error => {
    alert("Error");
});

In C# MVC the default content type for a POST request is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. In your js fetch example the default is multipart/form-data.
It should work.

This worked perfectly - just the content-type that was wrong
Thank you, thank you, thank you =:)
